# Javascript popup different size in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

How come this pop-up gets a size other than what I have specified, when testing it in IE6 and FireFox 3.6? Firefox displays it correctly but IE6 is smaller for some reason. (620x530 instead) How can I fix it?

```
<A id="myID" onclick="window.open('/sitecollectiondocuments/myPage.htm',&#13;&#10;'welcome','width=630,height=590')" href="javascript:void(0)"></A>
```

Comment: I think that in one of those browsers title is not calculated in height... but I am not sure in which one

Comment: IE6 includes the status/title/toolbar in its height. 
How can I circumvent this - make it the same size in as many browsers as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.open('/sitecollectiondocuments/myPage.htm','welcome','width=630,height=590').resizeTo(630, 590)
```